# Error Code: 1005 Can't create table (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

For some reason I can't run this SQL script on MySQL. I believe I have all the foreign keys set in place also. It runs fine if the variable type is an `INT`, however, if it's `VARCHAR` it gives me an error code # 1005. Anybody know what's going on?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test_table_2`;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test_table_1`;

CREATE TABLE `test_table_1` (
    ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `color` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(ID)
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;

CREATE TABLE `test_table_2` (
    ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `test_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
    `color` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(ID),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_color` FOREIGN KEY (`color`) REFERENCES `test_table_1` (`ID`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;
```

The problem resides with the line:

```
CONSTRAINT `fk_color` FOREIGN KEY (`color`) REFERENCES `test_table_1` (`ID`)
```

Comment: Post the error message

Comment: `Error Code: 1005. Can't create table 'frisbita.test_table_2' (errno: 150)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to refer `ID` column of type `INT` from `test_table_1` to `Color` column in `test_table_2` so it should be of type `INT`

```
CREATE TABLE `test_table_2` (
    ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `test_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
    `color` INT NOT NULL, --here
    PRIMARY KEY(ID),
    CONSTRAINT `fk_color` FOREIGN KEY (`color`) REFERENCES `test_table_1` (`ID`)
) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;
```

Basically reference column must have the same data type as the parent table column

Comment: However, what if I wanted to store only characters in that column of that table?

Comment: In the `color` column I meant to say.

Comment: @Donson - Then you are losing the point of creating foreign key. You should store the `ID` generated for each `color` in `test_table_1`